# Sorry, this action is not available in simulation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

My test invocation name is "Mrs Tang", so i input "Talk to Mrs Tang", but it responds "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"...

Does anybody know How can I resolve this error? [image]

Comment: Does your welcome intent have an "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME" event declared? It happened to me mostly when my Default Welcome Intent only had a "WELCOME" event

Comment: Thank you for your help.I did the google home sample that shown on the Google conference using Actions SDK, so there was no that Intent

Comment: It seems like you figured out the problem? Joyce Qi, good etiquette is to post your answer to your own question and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I still have this problem . The last result is I can't find my app in home controller on google device,and ""this action is not available in simulation" when I test in web simulator.

Answer (score 22):

According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app#preview_the_app):

> Turn on the Web & App Activity, Device Information, and Voice & Audio
>   Activity permissions on the [Activity controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) page for your Google
>   account. You need to do this to use the Actions Simulator, which lets
>   you test your actions on the web without a hardware device.

And I had do what [Jeremy Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44602713/2069407) suggested.  To add a second google  account in the **GCP IAM console** with a **viewer action permission** and then login with this second google account in an **incognito window** for the web simulator to work.

Comment: So, you need a second Google account to use the simulator?

Comment: @deed02392, yes, a second Google account worked for me.

Comment: Perfectly working solution for me this one. Google assistant simulation wasn't workig for the dialogflow chatbot I created. Since I used my org account for setting up these projects and web activity option was disabled by the admin so I was supposed to move these to my personal account but then you solution helped me add new user to my project and assign role to access.

Answer (score 4):

I had a related problem (I could test with my main developer account, but not my test credentials). I eventually got it working with the non-primary account.

The missing link for me was that when I was viewing the simulator, I was actually signed in to two accounts, my primary google account (developer account, shows up in the main frame of the page, upper right corner), and the account I authorized when 'starting' the simulator (email address shows up in the simulator frame), which was my test credentials. The second test account repeatedly gave me the "Sorry, this action is not supported in simulation" message, until I:

1) Added the test account as a Conversation API Viewer & Client in GCP IAM console

2) Visited the 'create link' (the one that comes up when you click share) in an incognito window, and signed into the secondary account there such that I was signed into only one account in that incognito window.

After that, invocations connected to the app.

Comment: I got this to work by adding a user and using incognito mode for that user, still can't get it to work for the user that owns the service, even in incognito mode.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Gordon can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064186/gactions-project-getting-this-conversational-action-has-been-disabled

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are logged into the same account you used to deploy the test action and that the deployment has been done within the past half hour or so. If you have not set all the information on the [Actions on Google Console](https://console.actions.google.com/), you may need to use the invocation phrase "Talk to my test app".

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The account is same and deployment  has been done within the past half an hour , and I have set all the information that the action need,but it still response the same error .Is there any other reasons that will lead to this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes I run into the same error. I get past it by toggling the Active switch off and on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I encountered. You must be logged in via the secondary google account. Do logout from the account and login via the account that is paired with api.ai.

[why I can't use google action in web simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153333/why-i-cant-use-google-action-in-web-simulator/45254064#45254064)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by saying "talk to my test app" or typing it in to the simulator prompt, that triggered my app to start in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed to set the location first (it defaults to Google-Headquaters), if you are in some other region (like in germany as i am).
Then go on with "Mit meiner Test-App sprechen" (Talk to my test app), or whatever it is in your language!

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this message on my invocation, but on my my second input:*"Sorry, this action is not available for your app."*.
It turns out the simulator had left the conversation right after the invocation (and it did mention that in the small print).
This happened because I returned a `FinalResponse` for the invocation.  And a final response is pretty final, it will terminate your conversation.

So, after a `FinalResponse` you can only get back in your action/conversation by a [new invocation or a deep link](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/invocation-and-discovery).  If you want to suggest questions/inputs, then you should return `ExpectedInputs`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to turn on Web & App Activity to let group members use some Google Assistant features.(if you are using organizational account)

https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7219584?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any organization's Google Accounts then there might be an access issue. So use your own personal Gmail account.

Take a look [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304876?hl=en), organization's might not be given you access. So use your personal Gmail and follow the [Docs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html?hl=en#0), you will able to create your agent/ actions and able to test it with simulator as well as in android device.

Comment: I'm also facing the issue while testing one of my actions in simulator. 
But every answer here talking about Org account. I'm not using any organisation Google account and able to test other actions in simulator.

For added info, the app i'm trying is test is a "trivia action", created using default template and able to test the action during Jul 2018. But it is not working now in action simulator.

Answer (score 0):

At time of testing the Google Action you need to **set the location to the country** which you selected while developing or submitting your Google Action. 
By default US is selected in testing but if your action is for one particular country only then you need to select that. [You can see in image the field where you can select location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpUuH.png)