# Dialog Flow - Integration issues with Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

We are working on project using Google Home.

Details:

1. We have built certain intents in Dialog Flow. It has certain follow-up questions to get the parameter values, as a multi-turn dialogue. When testing using Dialog Flow, test console, I am asking

   1. Can you help in booking a table: It prompts back with right question (Where do you want to book a table) as configured in Dialog Flow
   2. Where do you want to book a table : I answer - "Some Restaurant". It prompts back with right question (When do you want to book a table) as configured in Dialog Flow
   3. When do you want to book a table: I answer: "Today" . It prompts back with right question (For how many guests) as configured in Dialog Flow.
   4. For how many guests? - I answer: "4 people." It ends the conversation,  as configured in Dialog Flow.

The above conversation works perfectly fine as expected.

When I test using the integration for Google Home (using simulator with action SDK) [See how it works in Google Assistant]

1. Invoke the app (by using the explicit invocation - Talk to [APP NAME]) - App gets invoked with the right greeting message as configured
2. After that when I ask the questions as mentioned - above - app leaves the conversation? Nothing is answered back.

Not sure why this issue is happening - anything I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: can you show us screenshots of your intents? Was there any message in the Error tab of the Google Simulator? What was the answer received when it left?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you using webhook fulfillment, or just Dialogflow at this point? (And, as @RémiC. says, it would be very very helpful to see full screen shots of each of the Intents)

Comment: Actually, it would *also* be useful to see screen shots of the simulator when it has the problem, as well as getting the contents of the "Debug" tab.

Comment: I am just wondering, if there are possible permission in this account which I missing?

I just checked, from my personal gmail account - this works perfectly fine.

From my office account (appdeveloper@zencode.guru ), the issue is there - so I am quite certain this must be some account configuration issue.

Any permission that needs to be enabled?

Comment: the office account is a gsuite account. What kind of settings need to be applied there for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For personal gmail accounts, the Web&App activity, when turned on, it automatically gets enabled.

For gsuite accounts, even when the Web&App activity turned on, it needs to be enabled by the admin of that organization. Only after when it is enabled, the simulator will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through your intents and make sure the 'set this intent to end conversation' is not set to enabled in Dialogflow (and if you're using a webhook not ending there).  Look down at the Responses section in DF.

Start with Welcome Default intent, and then check each intent, all follow-up prompts.

Comment: That is not set.

I am just wondering, if there are possible permission in this account which I missing? I just checked, from my personal gmail account - this works perfectly fine. From my office account (appdeveloper@zencode.guru ), the issue is there - so I am quite certain this must be some account configuration issue. Any permission that needs to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I think Actions straight up doesn't work for some (all?) Gsuite accounts, regardless of what permissions you set. Google knows but doesn't care. I spent weeks in an Actions support conversation on this topic and they ultimately punted me to the Gsuite team, who couldn't help. See also:

- [Sorry, this action is not available in simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341793/sorry-this-action-is-not-available-in-simulation)
- [Actions on Google won't respond to explicit invocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974522/actions-on-google-wont-respond-to-explicit-invocations/54985709#54985709)