# Jovo hello world app not working on office google account

Tags: actions-on-google, jovo-framework

The deploy zip when imported to my personal dataflow with api version 1 it works on Google actions simulator. But same zip when i upload to my office dataflow account it loads and everything but does not work on simulator test.
I am following this Jovo + Google assistance tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo-6ynZ0tTs

Error
Sorry, this action is not available for your app.
In the simulator, you are only able to invoke actions that you have added to your app. For more information on how to invoke your app, click here https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqIaC.jpg)
Do I have to so any other settings?

Answer (score 1):

To get Google Assistant to work on a Google office account, you need to ask your administrator to enable **Web & App Activity** settings.

They need to go into the GSuite Admin console, go to Apps > Additional Google Services, and click Web & App Activity.

Learn more here:

- [Use the Google Assistant with a work or school account](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7219584?hl=en).
- [Turn Web & App Activity on or off](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304876)

Comment: Thanks. that and couple of other ones too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341793/sorry-this-action-is-not-available-in-simulation