# The google action simulator can't reach my web server

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, simulator, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I try to test my google assistant application but the console.action simulator can't reach my web server **while the "dialogflow simulator" can**  ([Dialogflow simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPJaq.png)). I don't get any request from it in my ngrok console.
When I write in the simulator "Talk to my test app", I get the following error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.
```

.

```
{
  "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "",
  "audioResponse": "",
  "ssmlMarkList": [],
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": ""
  },
  "clientError": 8,
  "is3pResponse": false,
  "clientOperationList": [],
  "projectName": "",
  "renderedHtml": "",
  "previewStartTimeMicros": "",
  "isEmptyResponse": false,
  "agentName": "",
  "servingModelOutdated": false
}
```

All the solutions I tried:

- I enabled web & App activity on my personnal account  ([App activity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mev9y.png)).
- I enabled logs and applied the query "resource.type="global"" but no log appears **(except those resulting from the tests carried out with dialogflow)**.
- I have manually modified the webhook address of the simulator.
  [Webhook simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sZrx.png)
- I deleted my project several times and recreated it.
- I tried to invoke the wizard on my phone.
- I tried ngrok and localtunnel
- On dialogflow, I went to settings => Share and added a new user as Developper (a child account of my main google account). I then went to the IAM console and gave him the following rights: "Dialogflow API Client", "Reader". I accessed the simulator with this account via another browser but the error persists. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46698908/10519740))
- I activated/desactivated the webhook for the intent "**Default Welcome Intent**".
- I changed the language and the localization of the simulator by those which I had informed during the creation of the project ([Simulator location screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItVtD.png)).

Here is a extract of my code:

```
const {
    dialogflow,
    actionssdk,
    Image,
    Table,
    Carousel,
    List,
} = require('actions-on-google');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = dialogflow({
    debug: false
});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv, params) => {
    conv.ask(`Salut mec ca va ?`);
});

app.catch((conv, error) => {
    console.error(error);
    conv.ask(`J'ai rencontré un problème, pouvez-vous répéter ?`);
});

app.fallback((conv) => {
    conv.ask(`Je n'ai pas compris. Pouvez-vous répéter ?`);
});

express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using the Google Assistant as an Integration for Dialogflow? Can you show the steps you took to start testing it through the Assistant simulator? The Dialogflow project and the Assistant project are the same?

Comment: I didn't understand your first question. To test my application I do this steps: (I actually edit my message)

Comment: I go here https://console.actions.google.com/ and I select my project.
I click "Build your Action" => "Add actions". At the top right corner, I click on "Test" to "reset" the tests ([link](https://i.imgur.com/a56XutM.png)).  Once the test is activated I am redirected to the simulator on which I type: "I want to talk to my app".

Comment: Are you first invoking your action in the simulator, ie. "Talk to my test app"?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes

Comment: Now when I enabled the test I have this message in the top right corner of the simulator [link](https://i.imgur.com/mX10H6E.png) and after few second this error appear [link](https://i.imgur.com/nr5LdGo.png). My webhook still work when I do my test with the Dialogflow input [link](https://i.imgur.com/n46Sfxw.png)

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how you go from building your Action in Dialogflow to testing it with the Actions Console.

Comment: I think there is a problem between my google actions project and dialogflow project.

Comment: I think google has abandoned dialogflow in favor of Actions Builder because there is no way to "link" google action and dialogflow. All new projects created from the Action console redirect to the Action builder.

Comment: It seems that google "forces" its users to use the action builder. To use Dialogueflow you have to go backwards when creating the project and not select a project template. Example in this video [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daneQ8hA0HI).
I can create new projects using dialogflow but I always have the same problem even with a freshly created project.

Comment: Same issue I am facing. It's an existing project. DialogFlow can communicate with webhook and showing the changes that we did on webhook. I tried to change the Welcome intent text response in dialog flow. But those changes are not reflecting to simulator, when I test.  It seems something is broken between Google Action to dialogFlow. Or Google intimating to move on ActionBuilder rather than  DialogFlow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dedicated page for actions that are stuck in review, but it also offers some other support options.

https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support

Comment: I was in contact with a person working at google on reddit and he said two times that the bug was fixed. I tried the first time but it wasn't and didn't tried the second time.