# Gactions project getting this Conversational Action has been disabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am trying to push my `sdk` to `google action console` with this comment `>gactions push`,
I am getting below error.

```
Pushing files in the project "test-projects-396206" to Actions Console. This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...
Sending resources...
Waiting for server to respond...
[ERROR] Server did not return HTTP 200.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "This Conversational Action has been disabled. No changes can be made to the Action. You can still view the Actions until July 13, 2023. Learn more about the Conversation Actions sunset at https://goo.gle/ca-sunset.",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "This Conversational Action has been disabled. No changes can be made to the Action. You can still view the Actions until July 13, 2023. Learn more about the Conversation Actions sunset at https://goo.gle/ca-sunset."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So that I refer Conversational Actions sunset overview official page [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset)
.

What do I know if my Action is a Conversational Action?. I followed the step so I can't see the Conversational Action banner in `Actions project`

> If there is no banner, your Actions project is not a Conversational Action and won’t be affected. Note that the banner appears for both deployed and undeployed Conversational Actions.

My Actions project not Conversational Action even am getting this error while `push` or `deploy` the sdk to cloud.

I searched many place but am not able to fix those issue.

Answer (score 1):

Conversational actions are no longer available. Please read the [Conversational Actions sunset](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset) page to learn more.

Comment: Hi @Nick Felker 
Thanks for the answer. I under stand Conversational Actions sunset. but I checked in action console. My project not Conversational Actions. please check this screenshot https://imgtr.ee/image/2HZJU

Comment: please suggest me I want to create C2C voice integration. Which means my action custom intent will communicate with Cloud Function. I have already deployed custom intents in cloud function use with firebase.